# How to get a formatted json string from a json object?

Tags: json, bash, jq

I'm storing the output of `cat ~/path/to/file/blah | jq tojson` in a variable to be used later in a curl POST with JSON content. It works well, but it removes all line breaks. I understand line breaks are not supported in JSON, but I'd like them to be replaced with `\n` characters so when the data is used it isn't all one line.

Is there a way to do this?

Example:

```
{
  "test": {
     "name": "test",
     "description": "blah"
  },
  "test2": {
     "name": "test2",
     "description": "blah2" 
  }
}
```

becomes

```
"{\"test\":{\"name\":\"test\",\"description\":\"blah\"},\"test2\":{\"name\":\"test2\",\"description\":\"blah2\"}}"
```

but I'd like it to look like

```
{\n  \"test\": {\n    \"name\": \"test\",\n    \"description\": \"blah\"\n  },\n  \"test2\": {\n    \"name\": \"test2\",\n    \"description\": \"blah2\" \n  }\n}
```

I'm actually only converting it to a JSON string so it is able to be posted as part of another JSON. When is it posted, I'd like it to have the format it had originally which can be achieved if there are \n characters.

I can do this manually by doing

`cat file | sed -E ':a;N;$!ba;s/\r{0,1}\n/\\n/g' | sed 's/\"/\\"/g')`

but this is not ideal.

Comment: There is a [feature request](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1360) out for it, but currently there's nothing built in. I think it should be possible to build a function that achieves what you want, but I imagine it will be pretty complex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tojson` (or other json outputting filters) will not format the json. It will take on the usual compact form. There is a [feature request](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1360) out there for this so look out for that in a future version.

You could take advantage of jq's regular formatted output, but you'll want to stringify it. You could simulate stringifying by slurping in as raw input, the formatted output. This will read in all of the input as a single string. And since the input was just a json object, it'll produce a string representation of that object.

If you don't mind the extra jq calls, you could do this:

```
$ var=$(jq '.' input.json | jq -sR '.')
$ echo "$var"
"{\n  \"test\": {\n    \"name\": \"test\",\n    \"description\": \"blah\"\n  },\n  \"test2\": {\n    \"name\": \"test2\",\n    \"description\": \"blah2\"\n  }\n}\n"
```

Then of course if your input is already formatted, you could leave out the first jq call.

Comment: Nicely done, but it seems that `jq -sR '.' input.json` will do in order to preserve the line breaks in the input as-is.

Comment: It's unclear to me if the original input is formatted as desired. This should take care of the case when it isn't. But yeah, if it's already formatted, then that'll do.

Answer (score 0):

If your input contains only one JSON value, then `jq` isn't really buying you much here: all you need is to escape the few characters that are valid in JSON but that don't represent themselves in JSON strings, and you can easily do that using command-line utilities for general-purpose string processing.

For example:

```
perl -wpe '
    s/\\/\\<backslash>/g;
    s/\t/\\t/g;
    s/\n/\\n/g;
    s/\r/\\r/g;
    s/"/\\"/g;
    s/\\<backslash>/\\\\/g
' ~/path/to/file/blah
```

Comment: Okay, this is similar to what I was doing with sed. Is this ever going to backfire?

Comment: @Shea: This approach will never backfire, as long as you cover all cases . . . which I actually *haven't* done here, since valid JSON can also include carriage returns (`\r`). I'll fix that now. :-P

Comment: What about the rest of the invalid characters on here: http://json.org/string.gif

Comment: @Shea: According to that GIF, the only invalid characters are `"`, `\​`, and control characters. The above command covers `"`, `\​`, and all control characters that are allowed in valid JSON (namely `\t`, `\n`, and `\r`).

Comment: So can't you just do `sed 's/"/\"/g';'s/\/\\/g'` ? That covers everything, because the only character that doesn't already have a backslash is `"`. Everything else will be given their second backslash with the second sed statement.

Comment: @Shea: Although `"\n"` denotes a newline character and `"\\n"` denotes backslash-n, doubling backslashes won't convert a newline character to backslash-n.

Comment: In my case it does because it's going through a second layer of JSON (weird, I know). It worked for me! Thanks for all your help.